# Add an instance of a class in an attribute via XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hi have a custom class (a Button extended class) where i have a custom property of type Control.
I need this property to access another control an do something.

The property is declared as follow:

```
private Control mainTab = null;
public Control MainTab { get { return mainTab; } set { mainTab = value; } }
```

but in XAML when i use:

```
// "mainTab" is the x:Name of another control in this window
<CustomClass MainTab="mainTab" ....></CustomClass>
```

i got "Memeber MainTab not recognized or not accessible". Why?

Comment: Try making MainTab a dependency property and binding your control (using elementname) to it.

Comment: use dependency property

Comment: Like Nick said. Only dependency properties can be accessed in XAML.

Comment: @Core-One: No, that is not true. But they will not update unless it is a `DependencyProperty`, or the class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @Core-One It is well possible to set non-dependency properties in XAML. They can however not be the target of a binding.

Comment: You guys are right. I was a bit hasty and sloppy with my answer

Comment: @Core-One You can use also normal properties in XAML :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a binding to the named element by setting the binding's `ElementName` property:

```
<local:CustomClass MainTab="{Binding ElementName=mainTab}" ... />
```

In order to make this possible, `MainTab` has to be a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MainTabProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MainTab", typeof(Control), typeof(CustomClass));

public Control MainTab
{
    get { return (Control)GetValue(MainTabProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MainTabProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what is want.

Answer (score -1):

You have include namespace of your custom class in xaml, then you can use custom class

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
 <Canvas>
        <local:CustomClass MainTab=""/>

    </Canvas>
```

and class is

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class CustomClass
    {
        public Control MainTab { get; set; }
    }
}
```